# Measurable functions that induce the same multiplication operator on $L^2$ space.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Given a semifinite measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and a measurable function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, we can define the vector space $D(T_f):=\{g\in L^2(X,\mathbb{C})\hspace{0.1cm}|\hspace{0.1cm}fg\in L^2(X,\mathbb{C})\}$, and the operator $T_{f}:D(T_f)\rightarrow L^2(X,\mathcal{A},\mu,\mathbb{C})$   given by $T_{f}(g)=fg$.

Is it true that $T_{f}=T_{\overline{f}}\Longrightarrow f=\overline{f}\hspace{0.1cm} \mu$ a.e. I know it is true if the essential supremum of $f$ is finite, but i cannot prove nor give a counterxample if $ess\hspace{0.05cm}sup(f)=\infty$. Any help in either direction is appreciated.

Comment: Can you take a subspace $Y$ of $X$ for which $\text{ess sup}f|_Y<\infty$?

Comment: I think this works: Since $μ$ is semifinite, $T^{*}(f)=T_{\overline{f}}=T_f $ so the spectrum of $T_f$, which is the essential range of $f$, is a real subset of $\mathbb{C}$.  Hence,$f$ is real valued a.e.

Comment: Is $\overline{f}$ the conjugate of $f$, or just some arbitrary function?

Comment: $\overline{f}$ is the conjugate of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mu$ is semifinite, $T^{*}_{f}=T_{\overline{f}}=T_{f}$ so the spectrum of $T_{f}$, which is the essential range of $f$, is real-valued. Hence, $f$ is real valued a.e.